# Resource Not Found

Tags: android, android-logcat

I can't for the life of me figure out why I am getting this in my logcat:

> 11-16 09:08:04.287: W/ResourceType(348): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000004
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348): Unable to find resource: 4
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:907)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:595)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:693)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.onMeasure(ImageView.java:796)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1074)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:296)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:876)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1911)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ImageView(348):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:08:04.295: W/ResourceType(348): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000004
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348): Unable to find resource: 4
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:907)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:595)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:693)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.onMeasure(ImageView.java:796)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1074)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:296)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:876)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1911)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   11-16 09:08:04.310: W/ImageView(348):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:08:04.318: W/ResourceType(348): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000004
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348): Unable to find resource: 4
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:907)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:595)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:693)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.onMeasure(ImageView.java:796)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1074)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:296)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:876)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1911)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ResourceType(348): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000004
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348): Unable to find resource: 4
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:907)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:595)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:693)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.onMeasure(ImageView.java:796)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1074)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:296)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8322)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:876)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1911)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   11-16 09:08:04.326: W/ImageView(348):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

and I am wondering if this could cause ANR's?  I understand it is looking for a resource that is not there...it also happens here in what appears to be the notifications:

> 11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ResourceType(348): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000004
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348): Unable to find resource: 4
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:907)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:595)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:693)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:383)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RemoteViews$ReflectionAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:570)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:1082)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:1057)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.makeNotificationView(StatusBarService.java:765)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.addNotificationViews(StatusBarService.java:831)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.addNotification(StatusBarService.java:555)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.CommandQueue$H.handleMessage(CommandQueue.java:178)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   11-16 09:07:02.271: W/ImageView(348):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ResourceType(348): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000004
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348): Unable to find resource: 4
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:907)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:595)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:693)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:383)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RemoteViews$ReflectionAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:570)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:1082)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:1057)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.makeNotificationView(StatusBarService.java:765)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.addNotificationViews(StatusBarService.java:831)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.updateNotification(StatusBarService.java:658)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.systemui.statusbar.CommandQueue$H.handleMessage(CommandQueue.java:183)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   11-16 09:07:02.521: W/ImageView(348):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Both are for Resource ID #0x4....ideas?

Comment: Do you *have* a resource with ID 4? And could you possibly reduce the dumps to something less than a wall full of text?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're accessing the Resource which is not associated with the current layout..This gives no compile errors but at runtime we get like this..Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem sometimes arises when the drawables are not available in all the drawable folders i.e. **drawable-mdpi**, **drawable-ldpi**, **drawable-hdpi** and **drawable-xhdpi**. This may be a answer to your problem probably.
Thanks